# (Angular 6) Click the button twice in order to work

Tags: angular, forms

I have a form that I want to get filled with my database info.
In order to do that, I've made a method which is called in my NgOnInit, but that method needs to be called twice in order to work.

This is the method:

```
  ngOnInit() {
    this.typeForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      name: [],
      sig: [],
      camp: [],
      stat: [],
      campAt: [],
      campRep: []
    }) 
    this.getData();
  }
  
  getData(){

   this.getById(100).subscribe(x => this.User = x); 

   this.typeForm = this.formBuilder.group({
  
    name: [this.User.name],
    sig: [this.User.sig],
    camp: [this.User.camp],
    stat: [this.User.stat],
    campAt: [this.User.campAt],
    campRep: [this.User.campRep]

   })
  };
```

The thing is, when the page loads, I get the following error in the console:

> Cannot read property 'name' of undefined

But the **weird** thing is, if I make a button that calls getData(), when clicked, everything works fine. If I remove getData() from NgOnInit, I have to click twice the said button in order for everything to work. Though, I need the form to get filled as soon as the page loads.

What's going on here? How can I fix this conundrum?

Comment: Because you are calling this `this.getById(100).subscribe(x => this.User = x);` here in async. The value of `this.User` is not resolved yet, thus `this.User.name` etc is undefined when you are trying to initialize your form.

Comment: How can i make the page wait for the >this.user< to be resolved?

Comment: You can either put it inside your subscribe or on its complete callback

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Subscribe` is async, your rest of the code in `getData()` gets executed before the `subscribe` has finished.

Try to move the code inside the subscribe:

```
      getData(){

       this.getById(100).subscribe(x => {
         this.User = x;

        this.typeForm = this.formBuilder.group({

          name: [this.User.name],
          sig: [this.User.sig],
          camp: [this.User.camp],
          stat: [this.User.stat],
          campAt: [this.User.campAt],
          campRep: [this.User.campRep]

         });

      }); 


   };
```

Answer (score 2):

You get the error:

> Cannot read property 'name' of undefined

Because the class variable `User` would not be defined until your subscription finishes, the code below the subscription block will not wait for the subscription to finish.

Write all your logic under the `Subscription` of `this.getById(100)`.

You can make your `getData()` as:

```
getData() {
     this.getById(100).subscribe(x => {
         this.user = x;
         this.typeForm.setValue(this.user)
     }); 
}
```

You don't need to explicitly set all the values inside the formControls, You can use `setValue()` on the FormGroup to add the values as the structure of returned data is same as that of your form.